# Android Studio starts downloading gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have downloaded android studio and sdk and everything required but when I start a new project studio starts downloading gradle which is already downloaded with android studio. If I try to stop that download, it can't be stopped, I need to shutdown my laptop.

Please tell me why this happens!

And if I import any project then it shows a message that gradle build failed and tells me to install build tools **API Level 7** which NOBODY uses now a days. What's wrong with this studio??

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, .gradle directory of my home folder has files of more than **300 Mb** I don't understand what this android studio keeps downloading.

Please help me fixing this problem

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a feature : gradle downloads new libs and contents to build your project. You have to let it do it's job and have some free space ...

Comment: Look at the build.gradle in the project that you are importing. Is it using API 7?

Comment: I still use API Level 7

Answer (score 3):

That is normal one time download of maven gradle dependencies and packages. However it usually takes a long time to download and build. Not sure what are the reasons for this.

Android studio contains gradle essentials,  but for some reasons that is insufficient to run command line tools.

There is a workaround to skip this download by adding gradle repo directory to android studio settings (Configure --> Settings --> Gradle). You have to manually add GRADLE_HOME to the system PATH variable according to your operating system. Run gradle-v in command line to confirm everything works right.

Comment: @Apurva Android Studio will run "gradlew" and install the gradle version for particular project you are importing. Look at the "build.gradle" of the project you are importing.

Comment: @apurva it is usual to take some time to download that 50 mb so packages, not sure why it takes this much time download and build

Comment: @YashwanthKrishnan I use Linux (Ubuntu), Gradle path is already set and now studio doesn't start downloading gradle but it pops a new error about build-tools and its because 64-bit sdk is not available for linux but now I have installed required packaged to support 32-bit sdk and it works well. :)